# Rails 3 Action Mailer Gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am trying to understand how to properly configure Action Mailer for Rails 3 to work with Gmail. Read the [article](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3) by Ryan Bates and also read the [edge Rails page](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail) article. Ryan's article said to put the config details in `/config/initializers/setup_mail.rb` initializer file

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",  
  :port                 => 587,  
  :domain               => "asciicasts.com",  
  :user_name            => "asciicasts",  
  :password             => "secret",  
  :authentication       => "plain",  
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  
}
```

But the edge Rails article said put it in the `config/environments/$RAILS_ENV.rb`, anyone know which is the preferred way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it wherever it makes sense for your particular project. If you need different settings for different environments then do that, otherwise you can put it into an initializer.